# How to get integers from list where sum of them is less than X?

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

Sorry for the mess that was here.
I wanted a classic greedy algorithm for knapsack problem in haskell for integers.
But there was other question - how to refer to list in list comprehension?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand the question. Do you want to add integers together until they hit 100?

Comment: @Kyle I have a sequence of integers. I want to take first N of them, so their sum will be less than X, and N is maximum possible.

Comment: @Kyle Oh shi--, that's a classic, updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches to this:

## Generate all lists which are smaller. Take the longest

For every `n <= X`, generate `[1..n]` and check whether its sum is lesser `x`. Take the longest of those sets:

```
allLists x = takeWhile ( (<=x) . sum) $ inits [1..]
theList    = last . allLists
```

where `inits` is from `Data.List`

### Alternatively, we remember mathematics

We know that the sum of `[1..n]` is `n*(n+1)/2`. We want `x >= n * (n+1)/2`. [We solve for n](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%20=%20n%20%2a%20%28n%2b1%29/2%20solve%20for%20n) and get that `n` should be `0.5 * (sqrt (8 * x + 1) - 1)`. Since that's not a natural number, we floor it:

```
theList x  = [1..n]
   where n = floor $ 0.5 * (sqrt (8 * (fromIntegral x) + 1) - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give all the lists that its sum is not greater than 100:

```
takeWhile (\l -> sum l <= 100) $ inits [1..]
```